# Large C99 test file need

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c99

After writing a C99 parser, I'm looking for a large file of C code (precompiled if possible, though I might precompile it myself) that tries to cover as many difficult situations as possible. I.e. some typedefs, variables that make others invisible, structs, complex expressions and declarations, etc., and all that in various orders. The file should not contain any errors, but correct code (conforming to C99).

Of course, I could just take files of a big library. However, I wondered if there's a file with a lot of pitfalls/difficulties that has been designed just for testing.

Has anyone such a file? If possible, under an "open source license", like GPL?

Comment: Why don't you try different open source code? `Use gcc -E` to get pre-processed files. Also try your on your own code.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Such code will usually not cover many different difficult situations. Also, it will be complicated to extract all required compilation flags like include paths for such a `gcc -E` call.

Comment: if you can compile a linux kernel, I think that's all the validation you need. You would have to implement some gcc extensions though...

Comment: I think it would be much easier to find a lot of different codes than a single with *all difficult cases*. Anyway your problem is not so easy as it seems.

Comment: Perhaps you can try http://www.ioccc.org/years.html

Answer (score 1):

Gcc has a test suite available here: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=gcc/testsuite/c-c%2B%2B-common;h=bf54e70b98ebd961fd0a2049f5dadf4151e8fac4;hb=HEAD